# MS-SQL Database Restore - Only one Filegroup

Tags: sql-server, database-backups

I'm currently struggeling with the MS-SQL Backup/Restore.

Situation:
I have a windows-service running that creates frequent (every 15 min) automatic backups that are shipped to a network storage.

The problem: The database contains many temporal tables, where I'm not interisted in making backup of the history data.

Therefore I have moved the history tables to a second filegroup.

What I need is a backup that includes the database schema and the data of the primary filegroup only.

From that backup I need to restore a fully functional database again.

Furthermore the database is in simple recovery model and as I already mentioned I need to do it by sql commands and cannot use the SSMS to script the schema / data as I'm doing it from a windows-service programatically.

Thank you for any idea.

Comment: I must admit, running a *full* backup every 15 minutes seems over kill. Seems like you would be better off with the database in Full recovery mode and using transaction log backups every 15 minutes.

Comment: In fact we are creating a full backup every day and differential backups every 15 minutes. Log backups are problematic as we are in simple recovery mode.

Comment: Have you checked the [BACKUP (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/backup-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), [Full File Backups (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/full-file-backups-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) and [Partial Backups (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/partial-backups-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) documentation?

Comment: Sure we have checked that, but we cannot use partial backup as in simple recovery mode the excluded filegroups must be readonly. As they contain the historic data of the temporal tables, we cannot make it readonly.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft:  So there is no way to exclude some tables data from being in the backup.?! :-/

Comment: Then perhaps you should move to full or bulk-logged recovery

Comment: The only way to do that with backups is to use a RESTORE PAGE... But this will be quite complex to realize... Prefer having a CDC or use your temporal tables to deal with new values in a period of time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This is a bad idea.  You should use full recovery and log backups if you need the data backed-up frequently.
2. In SIMPLE recovery all read-write filegroups must be included in a backup.
3. In FULL recovery what you propose is technically possible (the best kind of possible).  You can take a backup of the PRIMARY filegroup, restore it with recovery, which will make all the secondary filegroups defunct.  Then turn system_versioning off on your temporal tables to make them updatable.

Here's a sample:

```
use master
drop database piecemealtest
go
/****** Object:  Database [piecemealtest]    Script Date: 12/15/2021 7:16:57 AM ******/
CREATE DATABASE [piecemealtest]
 ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'piecemealtest', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\piecemealtest.mdf' , SIZE = 8192KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 65536KB ), 
 FILEGROUP [fg2] 
( NAME = N'fg2', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\fg2.ndf' , SIZE = 8192KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 65536KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'piecemealtest_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\piecemealtest_log.ldf' , SIZE = 8192KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 65536KB )
 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [piecemealtest] SET RECOVERY full
go
backup database piecemealtest to disk='nul'
GO

go
use piecemealtest



go
CREATE TABLE DepartmentHistory
(
    DeptID INT NOT NULL
  , DeptName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
  , ManagerID INT NULL
  , ParentDeptID INT NULL
  , SysStartTime DATETIME2 NOT NULL
  , SysEndTime DATETIME2 NOT NULL
) on fg2;
GO

CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX IX_DepartmentHistory
    ON DepartmentHistory;
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_DepartmentHistory_ID_PERIOD_COLUMNS
    ON DepartmentHistory (SysEndTime, SysStartTime, DeptID);
GO

CREATE TABLE Department
(
    DeptID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
  , DeptName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
  , ManagerID INT NULL
  , ParentDeptID INT NULL
  , SysStartTime DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL
  , SysEndTime DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END NOT NULL
  , PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (SysStartTime,SysEndTime)
)
WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.DepartmentHistory));



go

insert into Department(DeptID,DeptName,ManagerId,ParentDeptID)
select object_id, 'dept' + name, 0,0
from sys.objects 

update Department set managerid = 4
update Department set managerid = 5

delete from Department where deptid %10 = 3

backup database piecemealtest filegroup='primary' to disk = 'piecemeal.primary.bak'

use master 
drop database piecemealtest

restore database piecemealtest filegroup='PRIMARY' from disk= 'piecemeal.primary.bak' with partial, recovery
--Msg 3127, Level 16, State 1, Line 71
--The file 'fg2' of restored database 'piecemealtest' is being left in the defunct state because the database is using the simple recovery model and the file is marked for read-write access. Therefore, only read-only files can be recovered by piecemeal restore.
--RESTORE DATABASE ... FILE=<name> successfully processed 393 pages in 0.010 seconds (306.396 MB/sec).

use piecemealtest 

select * from Department

update Department set managerid = 8 -- fails
--Msg 8653, Level 16, State 1, Line 78
--The query processor is unable to produce a plan for the table or view 'DepartmentHistory' because the table resides in a filegroup that is not online.
go
alter table Department set (system_versioning=off)
go
update Department set managerid = 8 -- works
```

Comment: Thank you for the example code. We will try it this way after considering the log backups first.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to do it by sql commands and cannot use the SSMS to
> script the schema / data as I'm doing it from a windows-service
> programatically.

You can use the [SMO API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/sql-server-management-objects-smo-programming-guide?view=sql-server-ver15) to script schema/data programmatically, which is what SSMS uses.

Comment: Or run each batch in the script separately, eg with a .Net SqlCommand.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider creating another database to [replicate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication?view=sql-server-ver15) data and objects from the target database, and then performing the mentioned backup (every 15 minutes) for this new database.